# "Duplicate" ARIA roles on HTLM5 tags

Tags: html, wai-aria

What I am seeing on the Internet a lot is that the ARIA roles on HTML5 tags are mostly an exact duplicate (in meaning) of the tag name itself. Why would you want to do that? I'd say you could deduct certain roles just by looking at the tag name.

For example on this "[ARIA Role Cheat Sheet website](http://mcdlr.com/wai-aria-cheatsheet/)" I see the following:

```
<nav role="navigation></nav>
<main role="main"></main>
<aside role="complimentory"></aside>
```

Also in Twitter Bootstrap in the examples a form has the role form: e.g `<form role="form">`

I'd say, no kidding? When it has something like a search role `<form role="search">` it actually provides context what cannot be deducted from the tag itself.

Is it correct to leave the roles empty in the earlier mentioned cases? Where it does not give any apparent extra information about the tag.

Answer (score 3):

The ARIA (Accessible Rich Internet Applications) attributes are meant to be used for elements that are used to create a user interface in a manner that cannot be deduced from the markup otherwise. The reason is that this may help user agents and assistive software to help the user with such elements. Think about a `span` element that acts as a submit button, or as a checkbox, or as text input widget.

So we are not expected to use ARIA attributes for elements used in their simple, natural meanings. Thus, it is in principle redundant to declare `role=navigation` for a `nav` element, since that element has this role as the default *and* as the only permitted role (as per current specs and drafts). But as @Alohci points out, the attribute may still help, if a user agent is advanced enough to recognize the attribute but not new enough to know the element.

The document [Using WAI-ARIA in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/) (Working Draft, 3 October 2013) presents some recommendations on explicitly specifying ARIA attributes, based on information about user agents. Such information is of course mutable, but we can expect that any attibute specified as redundant there will remain redundant. In particular, it says that for `nav`, `main`, and `aside` a `role` attribute should be specified, but not for `form` (because user agents surely know the `form` element).

In contrast, the W3C HTML5 draft, which was recently moved back to LC status, [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#aria-usage-note): “In the majority of cases setting an ARIA role and/or aria-* attribute that matches the default implicit ARIA semantics is unnecessary and not recommended as these properties are already set by the browser.” It specifically says that the `role` attribute should not be set for `nav`, `main`, or `aside` when its value would match the default value.

Answer (score 2):

WAI-ARIA is older than HTML5. Screen readers implemented support for ARIA roles before HTML5 was mainstream, so for some users the ARIA roles provide benefit even when the equivalent HTML5 elements do not.

Although screen readers are catching up, remember that upgrading a screen reader (unlike upgrading a browser) is an expensive process, so old screen readers are in use far longer than old browsers.